# How to check for details of subquery output?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE t3
SET    somevalue  = (SELECT t2.id
                  FROM   table1 t1
                         JOIN table2 t2
                           ON t1.fk_table2_id = t2.id
                  WHERE  t3.id = t1.fk_table3_id)
FROM   table3 t3
```

The subquery *SELECT t2.id FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ...* returns 2+ values at some place in my SQL Server 20008 DB. Is there an easy way to figure out where it fails? Or is there another way to update a column in one table with values from another?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try using TOP 1 in your subquery. Obviously it looks like there is some inconsistent data, at least as per your thinking. So if you're happy to ignore that then top 1 should fix your immediate problem

Comment: Yeah, I already tried top 1 on the subquery, problem is, I am not sure if the results are correct, so I wanted to see where it fails to check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ts.id` is unique, you can find out where its returning more then 1 row, use a SELECT (omit the `table3` from the query if `t1.fk_table3_id` really is a foreign key constraint):

```
SELECT t3.id, COUNT(*)
FROM  table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.fk_table2_id = t2.id
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.fk_table3_id
GROUP BY t3.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to figure it out ... its ok to use top 1 in my case, Thanks!